# Remove 1 namespace from elememt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

currently I have an XML document where the root node has 2 namespaces listed something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns = "www.ns1.com"
    xmlns:ns2 = "www.ns2.com">
    <node1>
            <node2 addy1="something">value</node2>
    </node1>
</Document>
```

my current transformation looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@addy1"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The resulting xml is almost perfect except I would like to exclude xmlns:ns2 from the Document element (xmlns is fine)  What do i need to add to get copy just the default namespace with Document, but not xmlns2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@addy1"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBsN

Comment: Worked!  Thanks Martin